# Efficient layout for resource extraction and P2 production in PI

Tags: eve-online

I played around with PI a while ago in high-sec, but chose a rather bad product and didn't earn enough money for it to be worthwile. I want to give PI a second shot now in low-sec and I'm wondering about the layout for my planet.

I want to minimize the amount of hauling required, so I'm planning to search for a planet where I can extract two resources and produce one P2 product on the same planet.

My basic idea would be to center everything around a Launchpad that also serves as final storage for the P2 product. My main concerns are how to efficiently buffer the intermediate products. Is it better to add storage facilites for that, or should everything go into the single launchpad and be redirected from there? Any other aspects I should take into account?

Answer (score 5):

For P2 production, this is the kind of setup that I've found to be highly successful:

- Create one extractor for one resource (say, Aqueous Liquids) right in the middle of the best constant source on the planet.  Note that there are temporary "hot-spots" that you can mine out, and constant "resource production spots" that will always replenish.  While the hot-spots are great sources of resources (ha-ha), they'll be gone in a day or two.
- Repeat for another resource (say, Ionic Solutions).
- Link each extractor to a Launchpad which is as close as possible to the extractor and also along a line (an imaginary line, but you can create a temporary link to help) that connects to two extractors, route all output from the extractor to its Launchpad.
- Create a basic factory to process the resource into a P1 material (say, Aqueous Liquids into Water), also as close as possible to the Launchpad and also along a line connecting both Launchpads.  Repeat until your average extractor output can reliably be processed into P1 materials.  You don't want resources filling up your Launchpad, and you don't want factories with nothing to do.  Each basic factory will take its input from the Launchpad, and output to the same Launchpad.
- Create another basic factory on the other end of the line to process the other resource into another P1 material (say, Ionic Solutions into Electrolytes) the same way.
- Create an advanced factory, again along the line connecting both Launchpads and as close as possible to one basic factory, to process two P1 materials (say, Water and Electrolytes into Coolant).
- Repeat for the line of basic factories that doesn't have an advanced factory next to it.
- Now create a ridiculously long link to finally connect the two advanced factories.  Route one input for each advanced factory from each Launchpad.  Route both outputs to the same Launchpad, the one that will build up less over time.

I found that I could run pretty reliably with 3 Advanced Factories, 6 Basic Factories, and about 5 Extractor Heads per resource.  The overall picture is much like a barbell with a circle of extractor heads sprouting out of each end of a long bar connecting two points of high resource output on a planet.  You'll have to find a way to make that line as short as possible to maximize your usage of power for resource extraction while also having the extractors on reliable extraction locations.  It's a difficult balancing act, but preparing with planet scouting and choosing good locations will create a P2 production line that you can really crank the iskies out of.

Here's a link that talks a little bit more about the general process of [doing PI for P2 production](http://talocanunited.com/wordpress/guides-new-wormhole-planetary-interaction-pi/).
Note how he has to upgrade his long links (which is very expensive) and I've avoided that with 2 Launchpads.  Note also how he's not using his factories to reduce the length of his link and I am.  Those would be the main reasons I do it the way I do, but YMMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the single launchpad to start with. If you find you need more space, you can always add storage later ( you really shouldn't need it ).

Similarly, a couple of points to keep in mind:

- Try to keep your buildings as close together as possible.
- Make sure to properly map the entire planet and look for all of the raw mats you will need for your P2 product. Try to place in an area with good amounts.
- Try to get roughly equal levels of mats incoming at a time.
- For optimal usage, invest some time and energy into a (gasp) spreadsheet. It will definitely give you an edge into how much you are producing/what you may need to look for.

Comment: Spreadsheets in Space!

Answer (score 3):

I run P0~P2 production in 0.0 space to pretty much pay out most of a PLEX for my eve guys every month. In high-sec, I don't imagine the setting to make a decent amount of side cash to be any different, though, except maybe your yields.

I use a setup that relies on channeling everything through a single launchpad, using three basic factories each for two resources, and three advanced processors to take product from one of each of the basics to filter into a P2, which is sent to the launchpad. This can easily produce POS goods such as Enriched Uranium, Coolant, Transmitters, and other stuff on single planets, provided you can upgrade your command centers accordingly. Plus some of these goods are consistently in good demand

You could also check out this video. Forgive any, uh, colourful language, as it's done by an angry member of GoonSwarm

Drop it on a plasma planet. Get Enriched Uranium. Get money, get paid.

- Don't attempt PI until you get both Command Center Upgrades 4 and Interplanetary Consolidation 4. Don't run extraction cycles shorter than 24 hours. Don't do PI on planets too far away from freight service pickup points or market hubs.
- Your goal is to produce 432,000 P0s of each type per day for a setup with 3 Advanced Industry Facilities.
- If you're finding it hard to meet that number, do 2+2 Basic Industry Facilities and 2 Advanced Industry Facilities. Your goal will now be 288,000 P0s per day. Obviously this will be less money but its also less effort.
- With CCU4 you can have 6 basic industry, 3 advanced industry, and 6 extractor heads on most planets. This should allow you to comfortably run 24 hour extraction cycles while meeting the quota your factories' need. If the planet has been plundered by your fellow goons, however, you'll need CCU5 to run such a setup. CCU5 is the AWU5 of PI, and highly recommended because it makes you not want to cut yourself when you do PI on several characters.
- You don't technically need planetology skills, but they're highly recommended. They make it easier to find resource hotspots on planets.
- Why plasma planets? Because they make enriched uranium. The goal of this setup is low effort, and that means products that will always be in stable demand (read: POS fuel) and at a good price point, which considering planet/resource rarity means that enriched uranium (only on plasma) and coolant (only on storm, in practice) will be ahead of the curve. Q&A near the end touches more on this.
- Place structures as close as possible, for less powergrid drain from your links.
- If you find that your launchpad is overflowing with P0s, consider adding an Storage Facility to the setup. Route both Extractor outputs to it, and keep all Industry Facility output (P1-P2) to the Launchpad.